# How to call a method in a JavaScript include from typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The include I'm using is stacktrace.js

This include provides a call to retrieve the stacktrace by calling StaceTrace.get()

How can I call this method from typescript?  I've seen an example where you can declare a variable in ts with the same name as the method but I can't do that because the method is on the StackTrace object.

This is killing me.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything you reference in your TypeScript code has to be defined in TypeScript itself. You can reference JavaScript code that is defined in some JS file using the “declare” keyword as seen in the example below.

[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnqBC.png)

Comment: But can I declare a function with a . In the name?  In my case StackTrace.get(). ?

Comment: No you don't need a . . You can save the return statement of the js function in a ts variable.

Comment: But your example has a js file with a method called getCirclearea.  So you declare a function in ts with that same name.  But the method I want to call in my js file is on the StackTrace object. What would the declare statement look like in my case?

Comment: When you import the .js file with <script> you can reference on it without the filename. To call this function you can try something like this: var Variable = yourClass.yourMethod;